# Program.cs has been corrupted

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, corruption

My `Program.cs` file was working fine this afternoon.  I closed Visual Studio (VS2013 Express) and shut down my computer.  Then this evening I turned the computer on again and `Program.cs` now looks like this:

```
f£óö'ûRÏ>•]|êêlÇPš—·õGÉ+s
qÖY®ÓÇN­Ž9¯€8ï,? óQwÕ®Åy„Ùrsb^ ƒoÏEl?Qäº6z¹ Ü -³‡kwÎR®Q| €sáª  å²!dKË*:ÀyÉÿ?l
­Ã&Š‚Ëð.Š›ï,²©“Óü@q:VªÐMãÒŸå²‚¡ËÀÌ<öò§-ž‹66‚j$+”tVeÃÛSVÿ Ïr£pÉ'äûèk0Iœ¾Y/HÅ;vþ
DãjÊÕIÿóõ‘>¤¶ËLw¬,‚ÓHÃ¯’$t‡³Ywõ2ŽHíg3É·HVß{fÄèÄKõ™>§ïä ŽíC}r^—  x   èd’—X÷§º~qXPk#
```

etc.

Any ideas on how to recover it?  I tried running Recuva, but that didn't work.  There is no copy in the Backup Files folder for this project.

EDIT: I've confirmed that this is happening every time I exit VS2013 and then re-open any project. I was able to use dotPeek to recover the file by decompiling the project's .EXE.  However, the file decompiles in a format that requires substantial editing in order to do more work on it, e.g.,

```
xlApp=new Excel.Application()
```

becomes

```
Program.xlApp = (Application) Activator.CreateInstance(Marshal.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid("00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")));
```

I need a more practical long-term solution than repeated decompilation.  I'll get started with source control, but I'd ideally like to fix whatever problem is causing VS2013 to corrupt the file.

EDIT: This is now happening with other files, in the same project and in other projects in the same solution.  In reference to EBrown's comment about encoding, I checked the encoding and the affected files are in "Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001" (as are the unaffected files).  I am able to restore to the last committed version using `git checkout HEAD`, but this issue is making my work very inconvenient.  I'm hoping to find a solution other than reinstalling VS2013.

Comment: Sure, pull down the version that's in source control.

Comment: Something else you might try, after manually fixing up the file, is making the file read-only. (Also try explicitly denying write permissions, instead of simply setting the read-only flag.) If you're lucky, some component will throw an exception attempting to write to the file, and you then at least know which component is responsible.

Comment: Is this an `encoding` issue? You may wish to look into that possibility.

Comment: Do you use any VS plugins?

Comment: @adv12, no, this is a fresh install of VS2013 Express with no plugins.

Comment: @EBrown, interesting, `Program.cs` is encoded as "Western European (Windows) - Codepage 1252" and all other class files are encoded as "Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001".  Is this expected, or should I change the `Program.cs` encoding?

Comment: You should probably change the encoding and see if that makes an effect (it will most probably).

Comment: Also, if that has an effect then we can investigate *why `Visual Studio` is saving files in the wrong encoding.*

Comment: Do you have the latest [update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2829760) for VS 2013 installed? The Help->About window will tell you which version/update you are currently on.

Comment: @ArminSadeghi, I'm working with VS2013 Express, Update 4.  I can try updating to Update 5 RC, although the list of bug fixes for this update doesn't include the issue I've been encountering.