# Visual Studio is corrupting Program.cs every time I re-open the IDE

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, corruption

This is a follow-up to [my previous question about `Program.cs` corruption in VS2013 Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233451/program-cs-has-been-corrupted).  It appears that this same corruption is now occurring whenever I close and re-open Visual Studio, always just with `Program.cs`: when I try to open the file in the IDE, it instead opens in Notepad as gibberish characters like `ꍦ⟶勻ᛏ锾籝읬驐랗䟵⯉ੳ熍姖펮ᛇ굎`.

Is there a fix for this or do I need to reinstall VS2013?

Comment: could you share the file before and after corruption?

Comment: @sigil seeing as you definitely have experience being on StackOverflow you should've just updated your original question instead of creating a new duplicate

Comment: @heringer If the OP had the "before corruption" version of the file, we wouldn't be reading this question.

Comment: @hvd i disagree. he can make it up again, share it, and then when the corruption happen again, share it again.

Comment: I agree with @waltmagic. This looks more like a duplicate of your old question than a follow-up. One thing though that's very odd is that you say dotPeek gives you the same results. That shouldn't be possible if you're decompiling, but if it's picking up the symbols, it may actually simply be reading the same `Program.cs` file that VS and Notepad can't make sense of. Try turning off the use of debug information in dotPeek options to force decompilation.

Comment: @hvd, sorry, I need to update the original question: I was using dotPeek incorrectly, and decompilation successfully delivers a modified version of the Program.cs file.  But it's not reasonable to do this every time I want to work on the project.

Comment: @sigil Agreed, but if it helps you get your project in a state where it compiles again, you can then at least start using source control, as recommended in the comments on your original question, so that you won't need dotPeek for recovery in the future.

Comment: @waltmagic, I thought it should be posted as a new issue because I've discovered that it's occurring consistently?  That is, the scope of the problem has changed on further investigation?

Comment: Not sure if you have tried this on another computer with Visual Studio installed but if not, try it, and if that isn't possible you might try clearing the VS cache.  I've had some weird behavior that I could never figure out and clearing the cache fixed my issues. Try this link here --> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not.aspx

Comment: @sigil Since this is not a new issue, same issue, same problem, same outcome...just update the original question with what you have tried and believe it or not you'll probably get an answer quicker that way ;)

Comment: @waltmagic, I updated the original question.