# How do I replace a corrupt file using a git repository?

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio-2013

I've been having trouble with VS2013 corrupting my `Program.cs` file (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233451/program-cs-has-been-corrupted)), so I set up a Git repo and committed a version of my project.  Sure enough, when I opened the project today, `Program.cs` was corrupt.

So I guess I need to pull the working version of `Program.cs` from the repo and replace the corrupted version with this clean one.  I've been trying to learn how to use Git by reading [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2), but so far I haven't figured out how to do this.  Strangely, when I run `git status`, there is no listing of `modified: Program.cs` under "Changes not staged for commit:".  I do see `modified: Relinker.v12.suo`. I know that all of the .cs files in the project are being tracked, because after I add data to any other .cs file, save the changes, and rerun `git status`, the file ends up showing as `modified:`.

Sorry if this is a confusing question.  I'm just trying to quickly get my head around source control, figure out what's going on with this file corruption, and restore a good version of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can revert the workspace state of your git working-copy to the currently "active" commit (also known as HEAD) by running:

```
git checkout HEAD -- .
```

The command here follows the syntax:

```
git checkout [refspec] -- [path]
```

HEAD will be expanded to point to the (as already mentioned) currently active revision that's committed.

If you only want to change a single file use:

```
git checkout HEAD -- path/to/file
```

Comment: I figure that git doesn't recognize Program.cs to have changed, because the binary data (and thus the hash by which git tracks the data) has not changed, but I can't confirm that...